# image processing in vc++ using MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, image-processing

I want to perform the following artistic effect with my MFC app.
Can anyone tell me, how to perform it ?

**Input Image :**
[alt text http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/1351/11input.jpg](http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/1351/11input.jpg)

**Output Image :**
[alt text http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/7939/43output.jpg](http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/7939/43output.jpg)

Waiting for the reply...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you asking about how to perform image manipulation in general in MFC, or how to achieve this particular effect?

Comment: I want to achieve this particular effect.
And I want to achieve it without any image processing library.Basically I have to write an algorithm for it.It looks like some glass effect.
Can you help me in it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MFC doesn't include image processing functions (except some basic GDI functions). So you will need to use an image processing library, or implement everything on your own.

Comment: Basically I have to implement it on my own.
Do you have any idea on how to proceed on it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you do the artistic effect?

Its probably just some form of convolution applied to the image.  If so this post may help:

[How do I gaussian blur an image without using any in-built gaussian functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696113/how-do-i-gaussian-blur-an-image-without-using-any-in-built-gaussian-functions)

All you need to do is modify that filter matrix I supply and you'll get all sort of novel effects ...