# I want a method to remove the salt and pepper effect from an image without using the built-in functions of MATLAB. How can I do this?

Tags: matlab

I want a method to remove the salt and pepper effect from  an image without using the built-in functions (methods) of MATLAB. How can I do this?
i made this line

> > A = filter2(fspecial('average',3),RGB)/255;
> >
> > imshow(A);
> >
> > L = medfilt2(RGB,[3,3]);

but my teacher told me i cant use fspecial or medfilt2 as well 
so now i am at lost ,thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm used in `fspecial` is given in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/fspecial.html#bqkft1d) which is very simple in your case

```
>> fspecial('average',3)

ans =

    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111

>> ones(3,3)/(3*3)

ans =

    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
```

To implement the median filtering, you should traverse each pixel on the image. If `in(x,y)` is the value of the pixel at coordinates `x,y` in the input image, then `out(x,y)` will be the median of `in(x-1:x+1,y-1:y+1)` in your case with `[3,3]` window. I think, you should implement it yourself since this is a homework.

For your information, `filter2(fspecial('average',3),RGB)/255;` does not remove the salt and pepper noise. It blurs the image, i.e. removes the Gaussian noise but I actually recommend Gaussian window for that. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204880/198428) for creating a Gaussian kernel which may help you to understand `fspecial` better.

Comment: thanks for the help ,ya i am trying now to look for an answer and it kinda confusing as it is my first time using matlab and i hate math :P,thanks once again

Comment: @user1073372 - You may upvote an answer if you enjoy it. And mark an answer as "accepted" to officially inform the answerer that his answer was correct (and the best if there are more than one). Good luck to you with math :)

Comment: i want to upvote it but i still need 15 marks to do that :), and your answer is correct i am just having a proplem translating it :)
so i researched the codes again and found ,

>>J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0,0.025);

>>K = wiener2(J,[5 5]);
hoping it will be good enough for me :D