# How to gauss-filter (blur) a floating point numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, filtering

I have got a numpy array `a` of type `float64`.  How can I blur this data with a Gauss filter?

I have tried

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

image = Image.fromarray(a)
filtered = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=7))
```

, but this yields `ValueError: 'image has wrong mode'`. (It has mode `F`.)

I could create an image of suitable mode by multiplying `a` with some constant, then rounding to integer. That should work, but I would like to have a more direct way.

(I am using Pillow 2.7.0.)

Comment: Do you need this to use Pillow? If you have your 2D array `a`, would it suffice to "blur" the data directly without creating an image first?

Comment: Can you test by converting the mode like `image = image.convert('L')` and the apply `ImageFilter.GaussianBlur`?

Comment: @Carsten - How can I blur it 'directly'?

Comment: @JohnGalt - The array contains data like `0.03`. This cannot be directly converted to 'L', since 'L' means '8 bit greyscale'.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have a two-dimensional numpy array `a`, you can use a Gaussian filter on it directly without using Pillow to convert it to an image first. scipy has a function [`gaussian_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html) that does the same.

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

blurred = gaussian_filter(a, sigma=7)
```

Comment: Should be noted, that this only works, if you have floats, e.g. `test_arr = np.array([[1., 0, 2.], [2., 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])` will work `gaussian_filter(test_arr, sigma=0.7)`

Comment: @Boern Maybe it's a newer development, but I had no trouble using `np.int32` as input type and received this type also as output type (and the blurring had taken place).  Of course one needs to take values greater than 1 as input ;-)

Comment: If you're dealing with a 3 dimensional image, for example, you should use something like `gaussian_filter(img, sigma=(5,5,0))`

Comment: Just wanted to note that you can get the `gaussian_filter` directly from the `ndimage` import. I usually do `from scipy import ndimage as ndi; ndi.gaussian_filter(...)`

Answer (score 13):

Purely numpy solution using convolve and the separability of the Gaussian filter into two separate filter steps (which makes it relatively fast):

```
kernel = np.array([1.0,2.0,1.0]) # Here you would insert your actual kernel of any size
a = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.convolve(x, kernel, mode='same'), 0, a)
a= np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.convolve(x, kernel, mode='same'), 1, a)
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is my approach using only numpy.
It is prepared with a simple 3x3 kernel, minor changes could make it work with custom sized kernels.

```
def blur(a):
    kernel = np.array([[1.0,2.0,1.0], [2.0,4.0,2.0], [1.0,2.0,1.0]])
    kernel = kernel / np.sum(kernel)
    arraylist = []
    for y in range(3):
        temparray = np.copy(a)
        temparray = np.roll(temparray, y - 1, axis=0)
        for x in range(3):
            temparray_X = np.copy(temparray)
            temparray_X = np.roll(temparray_X, x - 1, axis=1)*kernel[y,x]
            arraylist.append(temparray_X)

    arraylist = np.array(arraylist)
    arraylist_sum = np.sum(arraylist, axis=0)
    return arraylist_sum
```

Comment: Great answer, as I am having difficulty combining Scipy into an exe, and have to stay with numpy using current operating knowledge. Expanding the matrix to 5x5, would it operate like a pascal triangle? My goal is to blur left to right, but retain similar clarity top to bottom. To get this I tried the following kernel: [[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.1,1.0],
                        [2.0,2.2,2.4,2.2,2.0],
                        [4.0,4.4,4.9,4.4,4.0],
                        [2.0,2.2,2.4,2.2,2.0],
                        [1.0,1.1,1.2,1.1,1.0]]

Answer (score 1):

**My take on how to do this with open-cv (cv2)**

I am using a Kernel size of `(3, 3)` make sure to adjust to your needs.
More details on configuration possibilities and more solutions with openCV are to be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html).

```
import cv2  # pip install opencv-python
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
```